# How to perfectly copy uv texture to another side without having to make them overlap?

Tags: texturing

I'm texturing a car and I want to copy the texture (that I've already painted on one side using Photoshop) from one side to the other, but I don't want the UV to overlap because I don't want the letters and the logo on the painted side to be mirrored. I tried using UVMagic to copy the texture from the faces but the addon just put seams on every lines and make the texture glitchy. Any idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Why not overlap the UVs? That's how I usually do it, create the logo I want to put on those sides, put the UV map of let's say the left side onto it, then scale the UV of the right side by -1 on the Y axis and place it on the logo as well. If you mirror the UV map, the logo will not show up mirrored.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly or not, but I didn't make the logo and the text separately from the mesh texture, they are in the albedo image texture that I've already painted and I wanted to know if there are any way to copy them so that I can edit the text on the other side or not (or if I should start over). I've updated my post with a picture, I'm quite new so sorry if the question seems stupid.

Comment: If you now flip the UV map of the right side so that it matches the left side, then the logo and everything would be perfectly fine and the same on both sides. Of course there's a lot of unused space in the right half of the image, but maybe you could put UVs for the roof and the hood there or something. If you wanted to edit the image or the text then I guess Blender isn't the right tool for that since it has very limited to none functionality for editing 2D images apart from texture painting maybe.

Comment: Couldn't you do that in Photoshop too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using a newer version of Blender. I tested the following with Blender 2.90.1.

I used the setup below to demonstrate.

[image: Cube with initial uv map and texture]

First you might want to copy your object. On the copy use overlapping UVs. In my case i mirrored the cube.

[image]

Then add another UV map to the object.
Next copy the old UVs to that map. You can do that by selecting both objects and press Ctr+L and choose "Transfer UV Maps". (Select initial object last, thats where the UVs are coming from). You now have you target and source UV layout on the same object.

Next go to the Texture Paint mode and choose the clone brush. Set the Mode to "Single Image"
Create an empty texture and choose the destination UV layout. Also tick "Clone from Paint Slot". Than choose your original texture map and one field underneath choose the original UV map.

[image]

Now draw over the mesh. you should see the texture beeing transfered from the original UVs to the new UVs. = )

[image]